# Java Multi threading consumer with ConcurrentHashmap strategy

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrenthashmap

we have a multithreads application with classic producer/consumer approach that uses a ConcurrentHashmap queue.

The consumer starts a thread the has an infinite loop inside with another nested cycle on the concurrent hashmap that read and remove every processed item.

I'm asking myself **if this code is safe/efficient respect to the "for" iteration** on the map and the "remove" for every element.

Running the code It seems correct...

```
new Thread(t.getContextName()+"-RespMsgThread") {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    do {

                        for (Entry<Integer, AbstractMessage> nodeEntry : t.getHtForResponse().entrySet()) 
                            {

                               --> Doing some stuff with the node Entry

                              // remove the node from the queue 
                              t.getHtForResponse().remove(nodeEntry.getKey());
                        }

                        yield();
                    }
                    while (!t.isStopControllerRun());

                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Context.getInstance().getLogger().info("ERROR: " + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex));
                }
            }
        }.start();
```

Comment: Please provide more details, question is not clear. By the way ConcurrentHashmap is by default safe for iterations.

Comment: What java version are you using?

Comment: Java 8. Is the for on entries safe respect consumers that put items in it and the remove?

Comment: Have you considered using java streams?

Comment: Not yet. Do you think I could have a more efficient/secure algorithm?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, its perfectly safe/efficient respect to the "for" iteration. There is one catch, because iterator for ConcurrentHashMap is weakly consistent, you can remove value for the key that you were not processed( Doing some stuff with the node Entry in your case).

So you can consider to call method

```
remove(Object key, Object value)
removes the entry for a key only if currently mapped to a given value.
```

Instead of plain **remove(Object key)** method

Answer (score 1):

When there are no items in the map you only yield, maybe you can sleep. As an alternative to sleeping you can use something like [BlockingQueue](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/blockingqueue.html). By using take() method on BlockingQueue you will get the item as soon as it is inserted.
You can also use [poll(timeout, timeunit)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#poll-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) method for checking if the thread is stopped.